# Whatsapp: Continous loop of messages backup and no text box to type in Samsung S10

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, samsung-galaxy-s-10

Gentlemen,

Two problems I'm facing in WhatsApp in Samsung S10 (fully updated)

1- Whenever I open WhatsApp settings, a message appears "backing up your messages" once it is completed and I try to go back to chats and starts again and again for 3 to 4 times then I can come back. (Backup settings: Never and not able to link it to any google account)

2- In any chat, the text box at the bottom is hidden and I cannot type anything, the only way around is to reply to someone then hold the phone horizontally and then I can type and send.

This is really disappointing especially that I just switched from iOS to barnd new Samsung S10 to find these issues!

(Note: I used a WazzapMigrator to get all my WhatsApp data from my iPhone).

Answer (score 0):

Resetting an application usually solves such random issues.
Long Click on Whatsapp -> App info -> Storage -> Clear Data.
It will reset Whatsapp. Now you will have to use WazzapMigrator again to transfer your data. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The only way for fixing this was uninstalling WhatsApp without touching any backups or databases folder. Just Uninstall, restart the phone and install the app. It will restore everything.

It worked for me and everything is fine now.